# Is it possible to access a public AWS S3 bucket without providing keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I don't have any keys for S3, but a software I'm involved is built on top of a public S3 bucket. Is it possible for me to test it without providing any public/secret key in url/authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely... for example you can store the images you use on a website in an S3 bucket. They are simply links to files that anyone can access, IF you set the permissions correctly.

To set the permissions click on the item in the S3 bucket, choose actions, make public.

Comment: Thank you! I just realize my case is a different: I'm using the native s3 protocol from Apache Hadoop/Spark which doesn't support HTTP. But you still deserve the credit.

Comment: Not sure how you would do that, sorry.